# sorting an array dynamically without knowing existing dimensions

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I know that `ksort()` is used to sort array by **keys**. The max dimension of my array always differs. Sometime 2, sometimes 5, sometime 10 dimensional so how do I use `ksort()` to do sorting dynamically without knowing how many dimensions exist in it?

Thanks

**EXAMPLE ARRAY**

```
[2010] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [B] => Array
                        (
                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [Patato] => 
                                )

                            [C] => Array
                                (
                                    [Patato] => 
                                    [Zozo] => 
                                )
                        )

                    [A] => Array
                        (
                            [F] => Array
                                (
                                    [Tomato] => 
                                    [Apple] => 
                                    [Kiwi] => 
                                )
                        )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [A] => Array
                                (
                                    [Orange] => 
                                )
                        )
```

Comment: Can you post contents of a sample array and the sort criteria?

Comment: Sorting an array by the keys of its value is independant from deeper nesting levels of the values ('dimension').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to sort recursive:

```
function deep_ksort(&$arr) {
    ksort($arr);
    foreach ($arr as &$a) {
        if (is_array($a) && !empty($a)) {
            deep_ksort($a);
        }
    }
}
```

This comes from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php#105399